# WebService - xsd:Date field

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, xsd

I'm creating a webservice for a customer in ASP.Net v3.5.
Currently, we have the an object similar to the following that gets returned by one of the webservice methods:

```
public class blah
{
 public DateTime datetime;
 public int someData;
}
```

Now, the customer has sent me the following request:

> In your schema you have a single entry for a xsd:dateTime. Can you
>   split that into two fields one for date and the other for time. The
>   use of a xsd:date and xsd:time should be fine as the object types.

Obviously, I can alter the class as follows:

```
public class blah
{
 public DateTime date;
 public DateTime time;
 public int someData;
}
```

But I assume that will actually produce two fields of "xsd:DateTime" and not one of each as he is requesting.

Please can you advise how I would achieve the results my customer is expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Blah
{
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", DataType="time")]
 public DateTime time;

 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", DataType="time")]
 public DateTime date;

 public int someData
}
```

This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In .NET there is no `Time` object, this is part of the `DateTime` object.

I would go on having two `strings` objects instead

```
public class blah
{
    public string date;
    public string time;
    public int someData;
}
```

and then parse them into a DateTime object soon you get them

```
DateTime dateOut;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(
          string.Format("{0} {1}", date, time), 
          "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", 
          null, 
          System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
          out dateOut)) 
{
   // date is valid
}
else
{
    // send error back saying that DATE or/and Time needs to follow a pattern
}
```

---

To make a property assume a specific type you can decorate with:

```
public class blah
{
    [XmlElement(DataType = "Date")]
    public string date;
    [XmlElement(DataType = "Time")]
    public string time;
    public int someData;
}
```

but there are forums that .NET has some problems with this... give it a try and test it your own using Fiddler for example to simulate a call to your service.

Comment: but how do I provide the "xsd:Date" and "xsd:Time" object types in the WDSL / SOAP that the client requires?

Comment: .NET does not output such type. PHP or Java do. Even you override, you can get in trouble. Answer edited for this.

Comment: I know .Net doesn't have a "Time" type, but there has to be a way of telling the client you are expecting as "XSD:Time" type? Obviously, internally we could have that as a string...